# CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey failed when using SelfSSL on IIS6 with multiple Websites

Tags: ssl, iis-6

I have two "Web Sites" running under IIS6 (Windows Server 2003R2 Standard), each bound to a separate IP address (one is the base address of the server).

I used SelfSSL to generate and install an SSL certificate for development purposes on one of these sites and it works great.  I then run SelfSSL to generate a certificate for the second site and the second site works, but now the first site is broken over SSL.

I run SSL Diagnostics and it tells me:

WARNING: You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate but CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey failed

If I re-run SelfSSL on the first site (to fix it), the first site works but then the second site is broken.

It seems like SelfSSL is doing something in a way that is designed to work with only one Website, but I can't seem to put my finger on exactly what it's doing and figure out how to suppress it.  I would manually configure SSL but I don't have a certificate server handy, but maybe there is a way to get SelfSSL to just gen the cert and let me install it?

FWIW I have also followed the guidance of several posts that indicate changes to the permissions of the RSA directory are in order, etc. but to no avail.  I don't work with SSL everyday so I may be overlooking something that someone with more experience might notice, or perhaps there is a diagnostic process that I could follow to get to the bottom of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem today. Our IT guy said he solved it by basically using ssldiag instead of selfssl to generate the certs.
See the reply from jayb123 at this URL: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/15d22105-f432-4d8f-a57a-40941e0879e7

I have to admit I don't fully understand what happened, but I'm on the programming side rather than the network admin side.